# In Stay Tuned, why was nobody worried about Murray Seidelbaum reaching 24 hours?

Tags: stay-tuned

The Knables went into the satellite dish at 10:30 pm, as we know from Helen’s broken watch left behind. The implication is that the Knables were sucked in the following night, and they meet Murray well over 12 hours in, which should be far more than the 24 hours necessary for redemption.

At the very least it is long enough for the police to investigate and report that they are *still* searching for clues in the disappearance of the Seidelbaums, which would be at least a few hours. And that is before the Knables get sucked into the network.

Before the Knables go into the Film Noir world, we see that they are at the 18.5 hour mark, and the assistant says that all of the previous acquisitions have been killed except the Knables.

But on the off chance that it was only a few hours different, the executives should nonetheless be freaking out since Murray would be significantly closer to redemption than the Knables. So what gives? Was Mrs. Seidelbaum the one who signed the contract and therefore they didn’t worry about Murray? If so, why was it such a big deal to do the exact same thing to the Knables literally a day later?